# Adding a timer to html5 canvas game

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, timer

i was wondering if someone could help me out with adding a timer to my canvas game, the aim of the game is to dodge objects until you collide with one, i want the time elapsed to be the final score. I would like there to be a timer on the canvas, when the game is over i want the score to show. 
Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EXAMPLE](http://jsbin.com/EnAlImU/1/edit)

```
var startTime = new Date().getTime();  // set this at the game start!
var time   = 0;
var collided  = false;
var engine;

function collision(){
  collided = true;  // if element is overlapping set to true
  time = parseInt((new Date().getTime()-startTime)/1000, 10);
}

function game(){  
  if(collided){
    alert("GAME OVER "+ time); 
    return clearInterval( engine ); 
  }
  /* GAME LOGIC HERE */
}

engine = setInterval(game ,25);


$('button').click(collision); // just to simulate
```

Comment: You are correct on `new Date().getTime()` :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `var start_time = new Date().getTime();` and something similar at the end to determine at what times your game starts and ends. By subtracting those values you end up with the time in milliseconds that the game lasted.